# Is it a bug of tensorflow for feed type?

Tags: python, tensorflow

See the code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 100], name='z')
uc = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name='uc')
sc = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name='sc')


sc_one_hot = tf.one_hot(sc, 10)
zc = tf.concat([z, uc, sc_one_hot], axis=1)


sample_z = np.random.normal(size=[32, 100])
sample_uc = np.random.uniform(0., 1., size=[32, 2])
sample_sc1 = np.random.randint(10, size=32)
sample_sc2 = np.mod(np.arange(32), 10)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(zc, feed_dict={z: sample_z, uc: sample_uc, sc: sample_sc1})     # works well
    sess.run(zc, feed_dict={z: sample_z, uc: sample_uc, sc: sample_sc2})   # raises an error
```

`sample_sc1` and `sample_sc2` are both `ndarray` with the `size` of `32` and `dtype` of `int32`, and all numbers in them range from `0` to `9`.

`sc` is `tf.placeholder` with `dtype` of `tf.int32` and `size` of `[None]`. 
When I feed `sample_sc1` into `sc`, it works well, but when I feed `sample_sc2` into `sc`, it raises `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unsupported feed type`.

It is an amazing error, is it a bug of tensorflow?

Comment: I did not get an error when I ran your code.  Tested with tensorflow versions 1.8.0 and 1.5.0, Python 2.7 and 3.6.

Comment: @AKruger, I tested the code with tensorflow versions 1.4.0 and python 3.5 on windows 7.